# cannot convert ‘int (*)[L][W]’ to ‘int*’

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to refer to a 2d array in a void function parameters, the function will be called in the main, but I am getting an error of:

```
mmm.cpp:26:31: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[L][W]’ to ‘int*’
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void generateRandemMatrix(int L ,int W , int * arr[L][W] ){


   for (int i=0; i<L; i++){

    for (int j=0; j<W; j++){
        arr[i][j] = rand();
    }

   }

 }

int main() {

int *p;
int L = 10;
int W = 10;
int arr[L][W];
generateRandemMatrix(L,W, &arr);

}
```

Comment: `int arr[L][W];` is a VLA and is not standard C++. Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead if `L` and `W` are not constant expressions (`constexpr`).

Comment: Is that the **first** error you get when compiling? (It wasn't for me when I copied and compiled your code.) You should address the first error before worrying about the others, as the others might be (definitely are in your case) artifacts of earlier errors.

Answer (score -2):

Without std::vector

```
void generateRandemMatrix(size_t L, size_t W, int *a)
{
    int (*arr)[W] = (int (*)[W])a;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < W; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand();
        }
   }

 }

int main() {

    int *p;
    size_t L = 10;
    size_t W = 10;
    int arr[L][W];
    generateRandemMatrix(L,W, &arr[0][0]);

}
```

Comment: `int (*arr)[W] = (int (*)[W])a;` isn't valid C++. It relies on VLA extensions that gcc has on by default.

Comment: If you're going to play pointer games like this, at least use `void *a` as the argument type. That warns readers that there's something C-like going on.